# Why does DROP DATABASE not remove schemas and tables within the database (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql

I created a database using:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo;
```

Then I created a user specifically for that database using:

```
CREATE USER foo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'bar';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE foo TO foo;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE foo FROM public;
```

The user worked with the database and once he was done I wanted to remove it (was just for testing something without any relevant stuff in it):

```
DROP DATABASE foo WITH (FORCE);
```

So far so good, operation was reported as completed.
Next step was to remove the user as well:

```
DROP USER foo;
```

But that didn't work, *because the user apparently still owns objects* (tables, sequences) despite only ever working with the database I just dropped.
Somehow, the schema still seems to exist, but I can't drop it, because (afaik) that would require me to connect to the database which no longer exists.

My question is: where did I go wrong? Would I have needed to `CASCADE` something somewhere? Can it be a transaction issue - I thought `DROP DATABASE` always runs outside of any transaction? I was expecting everything to be gone once the database has been dropped.
(DB Version is 13.1)

Comment: I am inclined to believe Postgres here. You most certainly did create objects owned by that user in at least one other database. Just connect to every other database and run `drop owned by foo;`

Comment: That's it! I forgot to strip rights from the default postgres/public and the user managed to create some tables there. Why didn't I think of that - thanks!